# Knex promises generates type error

Tags: node.js, es6-promise, knex.js

I am trying to get knex to map an array into its constituent strings and insert them sequentially using promises.

```
.map(messages, function (message) {
  return knex.insert({contents: message}).into('newsFeed');
})
```

returns

`TypeError: expecting a function but got [object Array]`

Comment: It should be `messages.map(function (message){})`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
let arrayOfMessageRowsToInsert = messages.map(message => ({ contents: message }));

knex('newsFeed').insert(arrayOfMessageRowsToInsert).then(result => {
  console.log("Handle result if you wish, result);
});
```